# Where should I place a DB query for a layout in Yii2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

I'm working on a Yii2 project that has a standard header/left column layout. The left column contains categories, which should be fetched from the database.

Where should I place the query that gets the categories? In the layout's code would be against how MVC should be done, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definetely you should not place any SQL code in layout, it violates MVC pattern, the view purpose is display and not this kind of logic.

Because it's common element, the widget seems to be good option for your case. You can place your SQL into `run()` method, for example:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\widgets;

use frontend\models\tests\Test;
use yii\base\Widget;

class NewTests extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function run()
    { 
        $tests = Test::find()
            ->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(10)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('new-tests', ['tests' => $tests]);
    }
}
```

Fill widget view according to your needs, then you can display it in your layout like this:

```
use frontend\widgets\NewTests;

...

<?= NewTests::widget() ?>
```

Additionally you can configure widget as any other object that is extended from `yii\base\Object`.

Comment: @alexandernst I added example as well for better understanding.

Comment: Nice, let me test it :)

Comment: Could you tell me what is the default path for the widget views and for the widget's code itself?

Comment: You can see how it's used in advanced application template [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master/common/widgets). So for widgets it's `application folder / widgets`. You can also place it inside of a module. Default view path is `widgets path / views`.

Comment: I just finished testing this. It's exactly what I needed. Kudos!